# Get SSRS ReportViewer JSF Java

Tags: java, jsf, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

Good evening, I have the following situation: I have a system in JSF and some reports in Report Services (SSRS), which are in our SSRS server available for access, but I would like to be able to access these reports internally in the system and not external as is done today, ie access to the link reporting server, but the report is with all parameters in URL and everything.

I know there is a way to internally use the ReportViewer applications in C #, but did not and found nothing clear whether you can use in Java applications (JSF).

If anyone can clarify me this doubt or if you have any examples, thank you!

Comment: Is ssrs simple db access, ie you want to access db from a jsf bean and send it sql queries?

Comment: No, what I'm trying to do is like this example the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa337091(v=sql.120).aspx so I can encapsulate the SSRS to the web form system in jsf